# Show $\int_B h(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{x}) d\vec{x}$ depends on $||v||$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable and $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ a constant vector. Show there exists a **countinous** function $g:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$g(||\vec{v}||^2)=\int_B h(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{x}) d\vec{x}$$
where $B$ is the unit ball.

This question was originally in 3-dimensions but seems fair to assume it's true for arbitrary $n$. It's somewhat intuitively true since for two vectors of the same length, the integral should be the same due to symmetry (And I guess it could be formalized using an orthogonal transformation).

I thought about maybe using a change of variables, but the transformation $\vec{x}\rightarrow \vec{v}^T\vec{x}$ isn't $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is $\vec v$ a constant vector?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the ambiguity

Comment: Yes, as you said, use an orthogonal change of variables to show the integral depends only on $\|\vec v\|$. Then reduce to a single-variable problem by using spherical coordinates and you should be in good shape.

Comment: What do you mean by reducing the problem to a single variable? And isn't there a more explicit solution to express $g$? perhaps one that also shows its continious?

Comment: As I said, write the integral in spherical coordinates, and you'll end up with an integral of the form $g(a)=\int_0^1 h(ar)r^{n-1}\,dr$ (in $\Bbb R^n$). Now you can do single-variable change of variables and easily check directly that $g$ is continuous when $h$ is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: I don't really understand how you got to this form. Where's the angle differentials? And how come you got $ar$ that doesn't depend on $\theta_1,\dots\theta_{n-1}$?